# Extract tabular data from every Excel tab, and paste data on a single sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with 75 tabs-- each tab is formatted in the same way with two columns of words.  I want all of this data to be on just a single page, but I don't know how to programmatically extract tables from each tab and paste it on a single tab.

Is there a way to do this in Excel?

---

Alright, here's the code that I've tried:

```
Sub Macro5()

    Range("A1:B30").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Table 1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

All tabs are formatted in the same way, with data in all cells from A1:B30.  I'm thinking that the Selection.End command would go to the next available open cell and paste data from the subsequent tabs in that.

As of current, I would need to go to each tab and individually run this macro, except that it doesn't work because it says the pasted data is not of the same type/format of the existing data.

Any ideas?

---

Coding attempt #2- SUCCESS!!!

```
    Sub Macro5()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.activate
            Range("A1:B30").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Table 1").Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
                , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            On Error Resume Next 'Will continue if an error results

            Next ws
End Sub
```

Well, I hate to admit I'm glad you didn't just spoonfeed me the answer.  Good on you, sir.

---

Coding Attempt #3- Avoid Selections

```
Sub Macro5()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            Set Rng = ws.Range("A1:B30")
            Rng.Copy

            Dim ws1 As Worksheet
            Set ws1 = Worksheets("Table 1")
            ws1.Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
                , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            On Error Resume Next 'Will continue if an error results
            Next ws
End Sub
```

Not quite right-- it still works, but I'm not sure how to avoid using "Selection" when I get to the first workbook.  Is there a way to reference the most proximate cell without content?  I know the 'End' key can do this, but is there a non-selection based way?

Comment: Try recording a macro and see what code do you come up with. You can then modify that code to then achieve what you want. Give it a try and if you are stuck simply post what you tried and we will take it from there?

Comment: The deed is done-- thanks for the advice.  Let me know what else I can do to make the code work.

Comment: Gr8. Now all you have to do is to simply loop through the worksheets and copy the relevant "Range" and copy it to the `Sheets("Table 1")`. Wanna give that a try too ;)?

Comment: You're some kind of wizard.  I did it.  Thanks!

Comment: `I did it. Thanks!` I know this feeling ;) Ok Now that you have got the logic and the code working... Few improvements :) Instead of `.Select` and `.Activate` directly interact with the range. You may want to see this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select

Comment: Once you manage to incorporate the above suggestion I will then suggest 2 new improvements :)

Comment: Hmm.  Alright, I think I've done it, but I'm having trouble avoiding selections on the second half of the code (when I need to use the 'End' key to get to the last cell with content).  Any ideas?

Comment: Gimme 15 mins... framing an answer...

Comment: `Well, I hate to admit I'm glad you didn't just spoonfeed me the answer. Good on you, sir. ` + 1 For your Efforts and willingness to learn :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this code.

1. I modified your code so that it doesn't use `.Select` or `.Activate` at all.
2. I have commented the code so you shouldn't have a problem understanding it. :)
3. The code doesn't use `On Error Resume Next`. You should always avoid that unless it is necessary. Use proper error handling instead. Consider `On Error Resume Next` as telling your application to simply SHUT UP. :)

Here is an example of basic error handling

```
Sub Sample()
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '
    '~~> Rest of Code
    '

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

So this is how your final code will look like. It avoids the use of `.Select` or `.Activate`. It also avoids the use of `Selection` and finds the exact range **that** needs to be copied and exact range **where** it needs to be copied. Also it does proper error handling.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LRowO As Long, LRowI As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Set your Output Sheet
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table 1")

    '~~> Loop through all sheets
    For Each wsInput In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        '~~> Ensure that we ignore the output sheet
        If wsInput.Name <> wsOutput.Name Then
            '~~> Working with the input sheet
            With wsInput
                '~~> Get the last row of input sheet
                LRowI = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                '~~> Set your range for copying
                Set rng = .Range("A1:B" & LRowI)
                '~~> Copy your range
                rng.Copy
                '~~> Pasting data in the output sheet
                With wsOutput
                    '~~> Get the next available row in output sheet for pasting
                    LRowO = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                    '~~> Finally paste
                    .Range("A" & LRowO).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next wsInput

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: This is brilliant.  I never knew you could use range with the & sign like you did.  Great!  It means a lot that you would take the time to teach me all this.  Thanks again, and take care!

Comment: I am just passing on the favor ;) Many many many years ago there were many experts on forums like this who patiently explained every thing to me :)