# Extract one column of data from every tab and paste all data onto one tab

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with 102 tabs-- each tab is formatted in the same way with several columns of operations. I want to copy the same column of data from each tab and put it on a single tab within the same worksheet, but I don't know how to paste each copy into a different column.

This question is very similar to the one asked here:
[Extract tabular data from every Excel tab, and paste data on a single sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787183/extract-tabular-data-from-every-excel-tab-and-paste-data-on-a-single-sheet)

I have tried many variations on the following code, but cannot figure it out. I am getting the following error:

> Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

I have pasted the code below. Thanks in advance for any and all help!

```
Option Explicit


Sub CopyPasteCombineSI()
Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim rngSI As Range, rngHeading As Range
Dim LColO As Long, LRowI As Long, LastColumn As Long

'~~> Set your Output Sheet
Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dual Flow")

'~~> Loop through all sheets to copy and paste combined SI data
For Each wsInput In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    '~~> Ensure that we ignore the output sheet
    If wsInput.Name <> wsOutput.Name Then
        '~~> Working with the input sheet
        With wsInput
            '~~> Set your range for copying
            Set rngHeading = .Range("E1")
            '~~> Copy your range
            rngHeading.Copy
            '~~> Paste
            .Range("F1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            '~~> Get the last row of input sheet
            LRowI = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            '~~> Set your range for copying
            Set rngSI = .Range("F1:F" & LRowI)
            '~~> Copy your range
            rngSI.Copy
            '~~> Pasting data in the output sheet
            With wsOutput
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
                    'Search for any entry, by searching backwards by Columns.
                    LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
                Else
                    LastColumn = 0
                End If
                '~~> Get the next available column in output sheet for pasting
                LColO = LastColumn + 1

                '~~> Finally paste
                .Range(LColO & "1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            End With
        End With
    End If
Next wsInput

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Range expects a letter for the column and you are passing a number.  Use Cells() instead `.Cells(1,LColO ).` instead of `.Range(LColO & "1").`

Comment: Thanks @Scott Craner it worked!

Comment: Personally I would look at @ScottHoltzman has.  It will be quicker for lots of data in that it does not involve the clipboard.

Comment: I thought I would have to use the clipboard if I only want to copy values...?

Comment: Nope, if you only want to copy values the quickest method is to directly assign the values to the new range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what [@Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) said, you can also shorten the code to this:

```
Sub CopyPasteCombineSI()

Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim LRowI As Long

'~~> Set your Output Sheet
Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dual Flow")

For Each wsInput In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    '~~> Ensure that we ignore the output sheet
    If wsInput.Name <> wsOutput.Name Then
        '~~> Working with the input sheet
        With wsInput
            '~~> Set your range for copying
            .Range("F1").Value = .Range("E1").Value
            '~~> Get the last row of input sheet
             LRowI = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            '~~> Copy your range
            .Range("F1:F" & LRowI).Copy
            '~~> paste range to next available column, assumes headers in row 1 
            wsOutput.Cells(1, wsOutput.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

To totally remove the clipboard (copy and paste).

Use this:

```
With wsOutput
    .Cells(1,.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Resize(LRowI).Value = wsInput.Range("F1:F" & LRowI).Value
End With
```

in place of the two lines for Copy and Paste.

Comment: .columns.count would still be referring to wsInput on your paste line.

Comment: Holy smokes that runs fast! Thank you! I had to remove the `End If` after `Next`. Thanks again for the help @ScottHoltzman and everyone.

Comment: @ARubaDubDub - It's amazing what clean code (which takes time to learn) can do for a program :). Please mark as answered so others benefit going fwd.